# How to add styling to the root component dom element (angular selector component)

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, sass

I have the following component:

```
// Typescript
@Component({
    selector: 'form-button',
    templateUrl: './form-button.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./form-button.component.scss']
})
export class FormButtonComponent {}

//form-button.component.html
<div class="form-button-wrapper">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>

//form-button.component.scss
.form-button-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
```

In the html, will looks like this:

```
<head>...</head>
<body>
    ....
    <form-button>
         <div class="form-button-wrapper">
             <div class="content"></div>
         </div>
    </form-button>
    ....
</body>
```

I want t defined a width and weight to the `<form-button>` instead of in the `<div class="form-button-wrapper">`.

How can I do that?

Comment: use `:host` selector. https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/

Comment: @VladimirBogomolov Good! Can you write it as a proper answer?

Comment: Read this old post you will get your answer :)
[Styling Angular 2 component tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43613725/styling-angular-2-component-tag)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, just use the `:host` selector. It gives you access to the wrapping angular element.

```
//form-button.component.scss

:host {
 // insert your styles here
}

.form-button-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
```